# How to skip some seconds on countdown timer on button click

Tags: java, android

I tried with many ways to do my countdown timer to skip some seconds on click. But no luck.

Is there a simple or advanced method to do it?

To skip seconds on click.

Comment: Pause it and then start it again.

Comment: @Panteliis take a look at the accepted answer, it probably does the job for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550561/pause-the-timer-and-then-continue-it

Comment: I would like to skip the seconds on real time.

Comment: No that question is not helpful. When click the button to remove some secs from the time left. I have lost many days for that

Answer (score 1):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO-> Add check to see if timer value is greater than the value your subtracting
        // Otherwise your program probably crashes.
        yourTimer.addTime(-5000);       
    }
});
```

This way you are adding a negative value to your timer so it subtracts it. You can enter any value what you want 
I'm not sure what you want to achieve, so excuse me if this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: This is working? I thing that countdown timer doesnt have the method addTime();

Comment: @Pantelis go ahead and try to look for something similar! I'm not going to write your whole app.

Comment: I dond want to write my app. I just want a help on a help forum. This method doesnt working

Comment: You don't want to write your own app?

Comment: I dont want you to write my app. I just want a hand of help. If i use timer and no countdown timer will be ok?

Comment: @Pantelis Please mark it as the accepted answer if this helped you, so people know this is the answer!

Comment: Ok! Dont worry. I will try it in few ours